# Can you use a grayscale image with no alpha as a layer mask?

Tags: ios, calayer, mask

Normally if you install an image as the contents of a layer's mask layer, the alpha channel of the mask layer's image is what masks the other layer. I know how to do that.

I have a vague memory of reading that you can instead install a grayscale image with no alpha and use the brightness of the image as the mask. I've tried searching various ways, but can't find any documentation about that.

Am I imagining it?

It would be more memory efficient, and make your code cleaner, if you could draw into a mask image using a shade of gray.

Comment: That’s what I’m remembering? Can you post your response as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: It isn't "brightness" but something more like "whiteness". "Brightness" is a technical term that means something else.

Comment: For a grayscale image aren't brightness and whiteness the same thing? (For colored images, luminance is somewhat complex. For grayscale, it's a lot simpler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `CALayer`, the mask is alpha mask. In CoreGraphics, one can [mask  with grayscale image](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgimage/1456337-masking). Also, Core Image has [`CIMaskToAlpha`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIMaskToAlpha) filter which one can use to convert grayscale image to alpha mask.